# How to add/remove drives to Windows OpenSSH SFTP server?

Tags: windows-10, openssh, sftp, winscp

I've setup the built-in OpenSSH in Windows 10 and connected remotely via WinSCP SFTP protocol.  I seem to have access to all folders in my `C:` drive, but I cannot access the external drives of my computer.  Going to the "root" folder just lists the `C:` drive.  I tried creating a soft directory symlinks in a directory that I can access, but that doesn't seem to work.  They appear as files in WinSCP and I cannot access them.  How can I add them?  Also, is there a way to restrict access to certain folders if I wanted to share access to only certain folders of my server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While some Windows SFTP servers do implement a virtual root folder which lists available drives, Win32-OpenSSH does not. It redirects the root folder `/` to `/C:/` (or maybe to a system drive).

If you want to visit another drive, you have to manually change a working directory.

- In WinSCP GUI, you can do that using [*"Open Directory"* command](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/task_navigate#manual) and typing a path to the desired drive, like `/D:/`.
- In command-line SFTP clients, like OpenSSH `sftp`, PuTTY `psftp` or WinSCP scripting, you can use `cd` command, like:

  ```
  cd /D:/
  ```

There's actually WinSCP FAQ for [How do I change drive on the remote panel?](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/faq_remote_drive)

---

Regarding your attempt to solve this using a symlink: A *symlink* really shows as a file in WinSCP (as the server presents it as an unknown file type). But a *directory junction* shows as a directory (the server presents it as a regular directory, not a link). Though [since WinSCP 5.14.2](https://winscp.net/tracker/1704), you can make WinSCP try to enter "file" using <kbd>Ctrl+PgDn</kbd>.

Answer (score 0):

On server machine, change default command shell as "PowerShell".

```
New-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\OpenSSH" -Name DefaultShell -Value "C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe" -PropertyType String -Force
```

Refer [this link](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/openssh/openssh_server_configuration#configuring-the-default-shell-for-openssh-in-windows)
This change should solve your problem.

Comment: How does changing the default shell enable adding/removing drives to the OpenSSH SFTP server. I don't get it.

Answer (score 0):

used this to set up sftp
https://v2cloud.com/tutorials/how-to-set-up-an-sftp-server-in-windows

the \ is used by windows, and / is used by unix/linux...  when you configure ssh or sftp it provides a unix/linux like interface, probably if we go through the logs you will see an error for c:, but since it is windows default it sent you to c:\sftproot....
simply set
ChrootDirectory D:/SFTPRoot
in the sshd_config file

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

There seems to be a bug/glitch when using openssh with the default "cmd.exe" shell.  At least on my system, when you change the drive letter from c: to d: the dir listing doesn't refresh, even if you do cls first.  But with powershell, if you do cls in between, then it works.